# Basemap Invalid Syntax for mapping EPSG

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I have a doubt related to Basemap Background Map because my code is working in some cases and other not.
I have a region to plot, so I apply the following code.

```
import os
import csv
import numpy as np
from obspy import read
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlon=-66.68, llcrnrlat=-29.13, urcrnrlon=-62.69, urcrnrlat=-20.97, resolution='l',epsg= 4326)
m.arcgisimage(service="ESRI_Imagery_World_2D", xpixels = 6000, verbose= False) 
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries(color='yellow',linewidth=2.7)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 2.5), labels=[True,False,False,True])
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 2.5),labels=[False,True,True,False])
plt.show()
```

The code "epsg" is related to cordinate system based on WGS84 for plotting maps (GIS enviorement). In my case I apply the code epsg 4326 that means all WSG84 world data (https://epsg.io/4326). In my understanding I am able to plot almost all world region.

```
llcrnrlon=-66.68, llcrnrlat=-29.13, urcrnrlon=-62.69, urcrnrlat=-20.97
```

The last variables are the coordinates systems of the region (in this case North Argentina).

When I run the code, it does not work and I got the error:

```
    m = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlon=-66.68, llcrnrlat=-29.13, urcrnrlon=-62.69, urcrnrlat=-20.97, resolution='l',epsg= 4326)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However if I change the variables coordinates to

```
llcrnrlon=-70.21840 ,llcrnrlat=-17.74899, urcrnrlon=-66.90053, urcrnrlat=-12.5548773
```

I have the wonderful picture I attach.
[image: Seismicity Plot]

I am not seeing the mistake on the code (when I try to plot the North Argentina region).

Comment: Using espg sets the projection using a numerical code so projection=‘mill’ is not needed. Remove that and see if that fixes the error.

Comment: @Jason, I removed it and no positive answer, I will re install "basemap" in Python3x

Comment: I just tested out the code and it seems to work fine for me. This is the plot I get: https://imgur.com/a/toSUhTr

Comment: @Jason, for some weird reason my text editor missed spaces under the for loop, I posted the entire code but no image taking out the projection='mill' or keeping it.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason To solve the problem I re write the code and use an IDLE (under Ubuntu) for some weird reason the simple text editor (under Ubuntu) missed the spaces and then the mistake I reported

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I will show you all the code I am working (fast bulletin for spreading information) a map (with a background image) and some waveforms from seismic stations.

```
import os
import csv
import numpy as np
from obspy import read
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# ---- Title Box-----
def add_titlebox(ax, text):
    ax.text(.77,.82,text,
        horizontalalignment='center',
        transform=ax.transAxes,
        bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.6),
        fontsize=6.8)
    return ax
#-----------------------------------


arge='/home/tonino/Documents/Inv/ShE/191224_Arg/2019-12-24-1644-12S*'
#os.chdir(r'F:\Grant_Nu\191224_Arg')

# -- Image set up --
gridsize=(3, 2)
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (2, 0))
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (2, 1))

# -- data to plot --
data=read(arge)
LPAZ_Z=data.select(station='LPAZ')[0]
AOES_Z=data.select(station='AOES')[0]

t_lpaz_z= np.arange(0, LPAZ_Z.stats.npts / LPAZ_Z.stats.sampling_rate, LPAZ_Z.stats.delta)
t_aoes_z= np.arange(0, AOES_Z.stats.npts / AOES_Z.stats.sampling_rate, AOES_Z.stats.delta)


ax1.set_title('Deep Argentina Seismic Event 24-12-2019 recorded at RS-OSC')

#lpaz.times("matplotlib")

ax2.plot(t_lpaz_z,LPAZ_Z,'b')
ax2.set_ylabel('[C]')
add_titlebox(ax2, 'Broadband LPAZ [Z]')
ax3.plot(t_aoes_z,AOES_Z,'r')
ax3.set_ylabel('[C]')
add_titlebox(ax3, 'StrongMotion AOES [Z]')

# -- CSV files with information --

epi='/home/tonino/Documents/Inv/ShE/191224_Arg/epicentro.dat'
lat, lon, mag, depth= [], [], [], []

# -70.2,-30.0,-56.9,-9.1  All Bol y Some Arg

m = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlon=-70.20, llcrnrlat=-30.00, urcrnrlon=-56.90, urcrnrlat=-9.10,
            resolution='c',epsg= 4326, ax=ax1)
m.arcgisimage(service='World_Topo_Map', xpixels = 2000, verbose= True)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries(color='yellow',linewidth=2.7)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 2.5), labels=[True,False,False,True])
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 2.5),labels=[False,True,True,False])

with open(epi) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)
    for uhu in reader:
        lat.append(float(uhu[0]))
        lon.append(float(uhu[1]))
        mag.append(float(uhu[2]))
        depth.append(float(uhu[3]))

min_marker_size = 1.7
for lons, lats, mags in zip(lon, lat, mag):
    x,y = m(lons, lats)
    msize = mags * min_marker_size
    m.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=msize)

plt.show()
```

However now I am not able to get the background image (under Ubuntu) but under Microsoft Windows I got it. Any suggestion?, Did anyone experienced this behavior? 
[image]